# EXM Upgrade/Migration

Tags: exm

I am looking to migrate EXM 3.4 to Sitecore 9.2. The documentations are available from EXM 3.5, but I cannot find anything related to EXM 3.4 Migration.

Is the process same for EXM 3.4 as well, or we have to first upgrade it to EXM 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

There is no upgrade path from any version of EXM prior to Sitecore 9, except a very light migration of emails from EXM 3.5 running on Sitecore 8 2.5 or higher.

If you are wanting to preserve the messages in EXM 3.4, you must first upgrade to EXM 3.5 (which also includes an upgrade of Sitecore).

From there, the migration documentation you are referring to should work to get you to Sitecore 9.0.x.

Once Sitecore is upgraded to 9.0.x, then you can upgrade Sitecore to 9.2.

However, it should be noted that no real migration or upgrade path exists and that links will most likely not work from legacy emails.